Difference in sensitivity and specificity between caret and pROC results for many categories tests in R
I have 2 tests [let's say: CT_scan (gold standard) and PET_scan (investigational)] to assess stroke category. CT will report it as A,B1, and C, while PET has many categories in addition to that i.e. A,  B1, C, Cc, ...
Some cases did not get both tests so, I believe they can be excluded.
We need to assess overall accuracy, sensitivity and specificity then draw ROC for that.
Here are a sample dataset and my code based on many prior posts
(Link1 and link2):
######################################################################################
###########################       PET vs CT question   ###############################
######################################################################################

data <- structure(list(Serial = c(33L, 35L, 42L, 28L, 30L, 47L, 10L, 
34L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 51L, 52L, 54L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 36L, 39L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 48L, 49L, 
55L, 56L, 3L, 14L, 53L, 22L, 50L, 1L, 13L, 18L, 23L), PET_scan = c("C", 
"B1cg", "Ac+DRT", "A", "Ccg", "Bct", NA, NA, NA, "B1cg", "A", 
"A", "Cc", "Acg", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "Ac", 
"B1cg", NA, "A", "A", "B1cg", "B1c", "Bcd", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "Bdc", "Bpcg", "A", "Bpcg", "A", 
"A", "A", "A+DRT", "B1", "A", "B1", "Ac", "Ac", "Ac+DRT", NA, 
NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "Bcg", "A", "A", "A", "Bpcg", "Ccg", 
"A", "C", NA, NA), CT_scan = c("B1", "B1", "A", 
"B1", "C", "A", "A", NA, NA, "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B1", NA, "A", "A", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B1", "A", "A", "A", "B1", 
"C", "A", "C", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 70L), class = "data.frame")

library(caret)
a <- na.omit(subset(data, select = c(PET_scan,CT_scan  )))
addmargins(table(a$PET_scan, a$CT_scan))
x <- a$PET_scan; y <- a$CT_scan; l <- union(x, y);
Table2 <- table(factor(x, l), factor(y, l)); 
CM <- confusionMatrix(Table2); CM

# Extracting the Sensitivity and Specificity for each class

sensitivity <- CM$byClass[, "Sensitivity"]  # Extract sensitivity
specificity <- CM$byClass[, "Specificity"]  # Extract specificity

# Calculate mean sensitivity and specificity, excluding NA values and print them
mean_sensitivity <- mean(sensitivity, na.rm = TRUE); 
cat("Mean Sensitivity (excluding NA):", mean_sensitivity, "\n")
mean_specificity <- mean(specificity, na.rm = TRUE);
cat("Mean Specificity (excluding NA):", mean_specificity, "\n")

### To draw ROC ###
# As we are dealing with many categories, I have to draw ROC 
# for each against the remaining ones.
library(pROC)
a <- na.omit(subset(data, select = c(PET_scan,CT_scan  )))
### Draw ROC curve fr category A and keep its AUC ===========>
a$CT_A1Others0 <- ifelse( a$CT_scan=="A",1,0); 
addmargins(table( a$CT_A1Others0))
mylogit <- glm(CT_A1Others0 ~  PET_scan , family = "binomial" , 
               data = a); summary(mylogit)
a$Score <- predict.glm(mylogit, type="response" )
plot.roc(a$CT_A1Others0, a$Score,main = "PET vs CT", percent=T,  
            ci = T, print.auc = T, col="blue")
#==============================
### Draw ROC curve fr category B1===========>
a$CT_B1_1Others0 <- ifelse( a$CT_scan=="B1",1,0); 
addmargins(table( a$CT_B1_1Others0))
mylogit <- glm(CT_B1_1Others0 ~  PET_scan , family = "binomial" , 
            data = a); summary(mylogit)
a$Score <- predict.glm(mylogit, type="response" )
plot.roc(a$CT_B1_1Others0, a$Score,main = "PET vs CT", 
         percent=T,  ci = T, print.auc = F, col="red", add=T)

#==============================
### Draw ROC curve fr category C ===========>
a$CT_C_1Others0 <- ifelse( a$CT_scan=="C",1,0); 
addmargins(table( a$CT_C_1Others0))
mylogit <- glm(CT_C_1Others0 ~  PET_scan , family = "binomial" , 
            data = a); summary(mylogit)
a$Score <- predict.glm(mylogit, type="response" )

AAA <- plot.roc(a$CT_C_1Others0, a$Score,main = "PET vs CT", 
              percent=T,  ci = T, print.auc = F, col="orange4", 
              add=T); AAA

legend(60, 40, legend=c("Category A", "Category B1","Category C"), 
        col=c( "blue","red","orange4"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)


From the prior code, we will get the mean sensitivity and specificity of
0.3097 and  0.9699 respectively. For B1, it will be 0.0000 and 0.9622 respectively. However, when we look at the resulting ROC curve for B1 category it is very high for both sensitivity and specificity (the red curve).

Edits (gathering the groups together and using cross-validation):
data$PET_scan_ <- plyr::revalue(data$PET_scan, c("C"="C",     
                                                "B1cg"="B1",  
                                                "Ac+DRT"="A",
                                                "A"="A",     
                                                "Ccg"="C", 
                                                "Bct"="B1",
                                                "Cc"="C",  
                                                "Acg"="A",  
                                                "Ac"="A",  
                                                "B1c"="B1",   
                                                "Bcd"="B1",   
                                                "Bdc"="B1",   
                                                "Bpcg"="B1",  
                                                "A+DRT"="A", 
                                                "B1"="B1",    
                                                "Bcg"="B1" )); unique(data$PET_scan_)                                                
                                                
cbind(addmargins(table(data$PET_scan_)))

library(caret)
a <- na.omit(subset(data, select = c(PET_scan_, CT_scan  )))
addmargins(table(a$PET_scan_, a$CT_scan))

x <- a$PET_scan_; y <- a$CT_scan; l <- union(x, y);
Table2 <- table(factor(x, l), factor(y, l)); Table2;  
CM <- confusionMatrix(Table2); CM

##### To produce ROC differently but the best sensitivity is different # (lower) than the average of the 3 prior groups
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138751/roc-curve-from-training-data-in-caret
# install.packages("MLmetrics", dependencies = T )
library(MLeval); library(caret) ; library(MLmetrics)
a <- na.omit(subset(data, select = c( PET_scan_,CT_scan  )))

ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", summaryFunction=multiClassSummary, 
     classProbs=T, savePredictions = T)
rfFit <- train(PET_scan_ ~ ., data=a,  method="rf", 
               preProc=c("center", "scale"),  
               trControl=ctrl); rfFit; 
res <- MLeval::evalm(rfFit) ## run MLeval

res$roc ## get ROC


Any thoughts or advice will be greatly appreciated.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596611/is-there-a-binary-classification-metric-that-optimizes-the-count-of-true-positiv/597497#597497
